# When to restrict a class from extending a class?

Tags: restriction

Is there any point in any programmer's lifetime to restrict a class to extending this class?
Example is that I don't want `Package` to extend `Box`.

Comment: are you asking if you can stop box from being extended or stop package from extending box while still allowing other things to extend box?

Comment: Stop Package or any class to extend Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  In Java they call this a `final` class.  In C# they call it a `sealed` class.

It is done because you cannot always predict the many ways a consumer might extend your class, so to prevent you from having to design your class to account for all possible ways someone might extend it, you simply seal it and require the consumer to use composition instead of inheritance.

**Further Reading**
[Why Are So Many Of The Framework Classes Sealed?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx)